# SSRS make parent group heading show for all child groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS report with the following row groupings:

```
[Grandparent]
   [Parent]
      [Details]
```

Currently when the [Parent] group changes value, the [Grandparent] row will disappear in the report unless it's in a new [Grandparent] group.  I would like for the [Grandparent] row to always show even when it's the same [Grandparent] but different [Parent].  Is there a way to do this in SSRS?

Comment: Why not add another row above [Parent] group but inside the Parent group and get it to display the Grandparent.

Comment: But then it will show the [Grandparent] twice if the value for [Grandparent] changes no?

Comment: If that happens, You can get around that having a row visibility on the bottom one to check if the values are the same and hide it. something like =iif(Previous(Fields!firstgrandparentvalue.Value)= Fields!secondgrandparentvalue.Value, true,false)

Comment: that was it thanks!

Comment: sweet.. I'll add that as my answer and you can accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add another row above [Parent] group but inside the Parent group and get it to display the Grandparent. If the rows repeat themselves when the group changes.. get around it by  having a row visibility on the bottom one to check if the values are the same and hide it. something like

`=iif(Previous(Fields!firstgrandparentvalue.Value)= Fields!secondgrandparentvalue.Value, true,false)`